# ajax basics for beginners

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other,
    url: "ajax1.php"
}).done(function(data){
    $("#div").html(data);
});
```

I have the code piece above, I search the web but I don't know how to explain what it is for. Is there any tutorials of ajax basics explaining step by step of what
`$.ajax()` means, what `type:Get` does, what `data:...` does etc ?

Answer (score 2):

It is making an **ajax (asynchronous)** call to a remote page.

```
type: get
```

It is a HTTP Get request. The form data will be encoded in the url as query string values.

```
data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other
```

This the data being passed to the server page

```
 url: "ajax1.php"
```

ajax1.php is the server page which handles the ajax request and reponds back,

```
.done(function(data){
   $("#div").html(data);
})
```

The code which inside the done event will be executed once the ajax call is completed. In this case we will get the response from the ajax call to a variable called data. We are setting that as the innerhtml of some HTML element with an id div.

read this link for more info : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you, Could you give me an example of ajax1.php file ? For example, the above ajax query is to save 2 id's into the database, I have no clue how the ajax1.php may be written

Comment: @SesamaSesame: Sorry i am not a php guy. This page can be a php page which reads the query string vlaues and do the action.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other,
        url: "ajax1.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#div").html(data);
```

Its really simple, we start by declaring AJAX function, then we declare the method(get or post - just like html form), `data` is used the parameters to be passed through URL. `URL` is the file which is invoked(just like action in forms). This will invoke your ajax1.php file and return some data, that data is returned in the success function or done function. In your case the `data` is the data returned from your php file.